# pythonic way for axis-wise winner-take-all in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering what the most concise and pythonic way to keep only the maximum element in each line of a 2D numpy array while setting all other elements to zeros. Example:

given the following numpy array:

```
a = [ [1, 8, 3 ,6],
      [5, 5, 60, 1],
      [63,9, 9, 23] ]
```

I want the answer to be:

```
b = [ [0, 8, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 60, 0],
      [63,0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

I can think of several ways to solve that, but what interests me is whether there are python functions to so this just quickly

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to happen if the maximum value in a row is reached multiple times, e.g. `[1,3,2,3]`?

Comment: @DSM Well, in this case both are accepted

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`np.max`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) to take the maximum along one axis, then use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to zero out the non-maximal elements:

```
np.where(a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=True), a, 0)
```

The `keepdims=True` argument keeps the singleton dimension after taking the max (i.e. so that `a.max(1, keepdims=True).shape == (3, 1)`), which simplifies broadcasting it against `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is pythonic, so I assume the way with most python specific grammar is pythonic.
It used two list comprehension, which is feature of python. but in this way it might not that concise.

```
b = [[y if y == max(x) else 0 for y in x] for x in a ]
```